# How to assign `ref` to a component and pass it to a child as prop

Tags: reactjs

I want to assign `ref` to my component and pass it as a prop to a child. Below is my use-case:

```
  return (
    <div
      ref={ref}
      onMouseOver={isSelecting ? (e) => handleMouseOver(e) : undefined}
      onClick={isSelecting ? handleClick : undefined}
      className='rich-html prose prose-sm dark:prose-invert md:prose-base lg:prose-lg'
    >
      {parse(html, options)}
      <RichHtmlContextMenu target={ref.current} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

So `RichHtmlContextMenu` atakes as a prop this `ref` and do the following:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    refs.setReference(target?.firstChild as HTMLElement);

  }, [refs, target]);
```

Unfrtunately, this `target` is all the times `null`. How can I fix that?

I tried

```
const RichHtmlContextMenu = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, Props>((props, ref) => {...}
```

but then in my `useEffect` I can't access `ref.current.firstChild` as `ref` has `ForwardedRef<HTMLDivElement>` and I acn't access `current.firstChild`

Comment: You should be using forwardRef for this

Comment: See my updated question, still can access it

Comment: If you need to access the parent element, you might consider the good old DOM traversal instead of passing a ref around. Assign a ref to the `RichHtmlContextMenu` component (topmost element returned by the component), then you can use say `getParentElement` or use the `closest` selector to get the parent. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with `target.firstElementChild` instead of `target.firstChild`?
It seems that there is a little difference between both.